# Create numerous unique events

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, unique

I am writing a program with a lot of buttons(over 100), and each one needs a unique result, but all of the results are similar, this is the code of the first button

```
box1= 'filepath to text file'
def openfile(filename):
    filetxt = (open(filename,"r").read())
    return filetxt
    var.set(filetxt)

def Box1():
    var.set(openfile(box1))

openfile(box1)
window1 = Tk()
window1.geometry('450x450')

var = StringVar()

Button1 = Button(donut,text = "Box #1", command= Box1 )
Button1.pack()
```

each button will do the same thing, but access a different file, is there a more efficient way to do this than simply writing a unique callback function for every button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you'd have the files in a list:

```
list_of_files = ...
```

Then you would create a function to make a button which opens a file input:

```
def file_open_button(filename):
    b = Button(donut, text = 'open {0}'.format(filename), command = lambda: openfile(filename))
    return b
```

Now iterate over your list of files and create the buttons, packing as you go:

```
for f in list_of_files:
    button = file_open_button(f)
    button.pack()
```

Perhaps the thing you're missing is an understanding of `lambda` (anonymous) functions.  a lambda function is much like a regular function:

```
def foo(x):
    return x*x

bar = lambda x: x*x
```

The above statements are very similar.  e.g. `foo(x) == bar(x)` will always be `True`.

Comment: Thank you so much! and you are right, I did not understand lambda thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2):

All of your buttons can share a single callback. You can use [lambda](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to pass the filename to the callback. For example:

```
path="/path/to/the/file"
b = Button(..., command=lambda f=path: openfile(f))
```

Another option is to use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Some people think this is more readable than lambda:

```
b = Button(..., command=functools.partial(openfile, path))
```